# how to run two executable generated with different gcc version in same system

Tags: c++, gcc, load, runtime-error

I have two Executable generated with different gcc version
One is using `gcc 3.4.2` and other using `gcc 4.3.2` in my Linux box

Both has to be run in same environment i.e. having same **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**.

Currently path of `4.3.2` is placed before the `3.4.2` the `3.4.2` is giving error.

`libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by../../src/hello)`

I am thinking about the solution where I can store the information in the exe where to find the
loadtime files needed.

**I created below build scripts which are giving problem:**

Basically O3 option is doing optimization.

```
/opt/gcc-4.3.2/bin/g++ -pipe -O3 -c hello4_3_2.cpp
/opt/gcc-4.3.2/bin/g++ -o hello4_3_2 hello4_3_2.o -L$/opt/gcc-4.3.2/lib64/libstdc++

/opt/gcc-3.4.2/bin/g++ -pipe -O3 -c hello3_4_2.cpp
/opt/gcc-3.4.2/bin/g++ -o hello3_4_2 hello3_4_2.o -L$/opt/gcc-3.4.2/lib64/libstdc++
```

**Below script works for me:(With out O3 option)**

```
/opt/gcc-4.3.2/bin/g++ -pipe  -c hello4_3_2.cpp
/opt/gcc-4.3.2/bin/g++ -o hello4_3_2 hello4_3_2.o -L$/opt/gcc-4.3.2/lib64/libstdc++

/opt/gcc-3.4.2/bin/g++ -pipe  -c hello3_4_2.cpp
/opt/gcc-3.4.2/bin/g++ -o hello3_4_2 hello3_4_2.o -L$/opt/gcc-3.4.2/lib64/libstdc++
```

**Now:**

1. I wanted to know if there is any other way to achieve it.
2. Is there is any draw back of doing in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify an `rpath` when linking:

```
/opt/gcc-4.3.2/bin/g++ -o hello4_3_2 hello4_3_2.o -Wl,-rpath,/opt/gcc-4.3.2/lib64
#                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will hardcode a library search path into the executable.

You can use `ldd ./hello4_3_2` to check without running whether the correct libraries are being found.

Answer (score 0):

The [libstdc++ manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dynamic_or_shared.html#manual.intro.using.linkage.dynamic) lists several options